# Высокий TTFB в Open Server

Tags: wordpress, openserver

Разрабатываю WP сайт используя Open Server. Но долго грузятся страницы, на которых почти ничего нет. Как правило время TTFB 2,64s, только затем грузятся страницы. Та же ситуация в разных доменах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие еще настройки могут вызывать такие тормоза?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Настройка "установлен WP". Если конкретней, то в тормозах виноват весь установленный в ВП хлам. Ведь то, что на странице ничего нет, не значит, что установленные плагины не запускаются и не проверяют наличие чего-то на странице. Попробуйте выключить все и тему в том числе, и проверьте скорость ответа.

Comment: Не в эом дело. Создал чистый домен, выгрузил туда последнюю версию вордпресса, загружаю страницу из темы Twenty Twenty-One, все те же 2 секунды и больше.